# Setting up Sublime to use bash aliases & functions

Tags: bash, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I'm using sublime and would like to set it up so that my custom build system can see and use aliases and bash functions which I've setup in my ~/.bashrc, which works from my terminal.

In my .bashrc file I have a build function:

```
function build() {
    // various bash commands 
}
```

In my ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User directory I have a project.sublime-build file:

```
{
    "cmd": ["build"],
    "working_dir": "~/Mozilla/git-master",
    "shell" : "true"
}
```

which doesn't work.  How can I get sublime to see and use the build function defined in my .bashrc file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sublime can not read your `.bashrc`, so in order to use custom functions you'll have to create a `build` file:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

#contents of build() go here...
```

Save the file in `~/bin` and set it to be executable. Then, modify your `project.sublime-build` file like so:

```json
{
    "cmd": ["build"],
    "path": "~/bin:$PATH",
    "working_dir": "~/Mozilla/git-master",
    "shell" : "true"
}
```

And you should be all set.